# How can I know if a program in python is running in spyder?

Tags: python, matlab, spyder

I would like to know a silly question about using python. Currently, I am using spyder to write python. Take matlab as an example, when I run a program in matlab, I can see the word `busy` and I know matlab is running. Are there any similar signals which can help me to figure out if a program is running or not when I use spyder environment?

Comment: The red stop button in the top right of the IPython console?

Comment: @rinkert, (*Spyder maintainer here*) That's the right answer. Please post it as an answer below. We can't change the name of the window (as Matlab does) because in Spyder you can open as many consoles as you want (whereas Matlab only has one console) and some can be running and others don't.

Comment: Let me check it again, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a red stop button on the top right of the IPython console. It is grayed out when there is nothing running, and becomes red when the console is 'busy'.